# vb.net how to access embedding form?

Tags: vb.net, dll

Im writting a dll which inherits a listbox and want to access the form of the project which is using my library.

So Let's say you have a project 'bla' and a form 'form1' which uses my lib. Is there any way to acces 'form1'?

I need this, because I want to add more controls to 'form1' than just my modified listbox.

So I'm looking for something like:

```
EmmbeddingForm.Controls.Add(ButtonBla)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is always the wrong thing to do, you have no idea how to place the button correctly.  You cannot assume that the form doesn't already have a control in the same location.  In fact, the form doesn't even have to be the Parent of the control, it could be placed on a Panel or SplitContainer, etc.  The odds that the button overlaps another control or simply not visible at all are very high.  Getting the tab order wrong is pretty much guaranteed.  Way too many problems to solve.

Use a UserControl instead, it was made to composite multiple controls into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

[`Control.FindForm()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.findform.aspx)

```
Me.FindForm().Controls.Add(...)
```

Comment: ok but now you'll have to get the name of the form. I could make a property where the name is definied by the user but thats not the best way.

Comment: I don't get that. You have the whole `Form` object returned by `FindForm`. This object has a `.Name` property among others.

Comment: yeah but findform needs a name parameter

Comment: No, it does not. It needs a `Control` to call it from, and from an ihredited control that `Control` is `Me`. Click the link, or just paste the code line into a method in your UserControl that inherits from ListBox.